# Could not build the precompiled application for the device. Error (Xcode): Target debug_ios_bundle_flutter_assets failed: Exception

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/Got4R.png[enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Got4R.png%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eepST.png)

I want to build my app on my iPhone, but I keep getting this error "Could not build the precompiled application for the device. Error (Xcode): Target debug_ios_bundle_flutter_assets failed: Exception: Failed to codesign /Users/pacome/Documents/projets/eklezia/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/App.framework/App with identity C0A6A1F777F930232EE52EDF9CFD023F8EC6499E."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.